# Conclusively Detect a Process losing Focus

Tags: c, winapi

How do you conclusively detect when the whole application (all process HWND's and child HWND's) have lost focus. I need to know this so I can hide my main HWND. I cant just make the main HWND handle `WM_KILLFOCUS` because child windows could have the focus prior to losing it (am I making sense?).

I could subclass every child's window procedure and handle `WM_KILLFOCUS` but that seems like overkill. And a hook also seems like overkill - seems like you only use hooks when completely necessary otherwise your application gets flagged as suspicious.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! That works perfectly. If you make an answer I can accept

Comment: Just write a post yourself and mark it as the answer.